# Ruby blocks (need a solution)

Tags: ruby, yield

The problem looks like this:

> Write in the class Range method todown behaves like this (use block_given? and yield functions):
>
> (3..5).todown {|i| print "hi#{i} "} #prints hi5 hi4 hi3
>
> (2...7).todown #prints 65432

After at least an hour of googling I still can't solve this. I've got as far as this:

```
class Range
 def todown
     to_a.reverse.each do |i|
       yield(i)
   end
  end
 end
```

I don't know where to add `(2..7).todown` line to get the needed result.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is: how do I solve the given problem?

Comment: Justin, please edit your question to: 1) replace the characters around `hi#{i} ` that look like double quotes, but aren't (grrr!), with double quotes; 2) change "produces" to "prints" (assuming that's what you want) and 3) incorporate your comment in the question (then delete your comment). That should stop the downvoting and maybe even attract some upvotes.

Comment: Please, show us your code, and what you have tried to solve the problem. StackOverflow is not a "write my code for me" service. If you want someone to write your code for you, email me, and I can tell you my hourly rate.

Comment: All solved now. For some reason the online interpreter found at http://repl.it was giving me errors whenever I tried to execute code with calls to `todown` method. Everything seems to work fine on a pc interptreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

I realize the question is just an exercise, but one should be very careful about modifying Ruby's core classes. [Here](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2015/01/20/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/)'s one of many articles that discuss the perils of "money-patching" and steps that might be taken to minimize risk, or to make debugging easier when a core class patch explodes.

We now have a (somewhat controversial) alternative called "Refinements". [Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) was an experimental addition to v2.0. It was then modified and made permanent in v2.1. Here's how it would work here.

First, we `refine` a class within a module:

```
module M  
  refine Range do
    def todown
      reverse_each do |i|
        case block_given?
        when true then yield(i)
        else print i
        end
      end
      puts
    end
  end
end
```

Let's try it:

```
(2...7).todown
  #-> NoMethodError: undefined method `todown' for 2...7:Range
```

Whoops! We've created the refinement, but haven't activated it. To do that we use the keyword `using`:

```
using M
(2...7).todown
  #-> 65432
(3..5).todown { |i| print "hi#{i} " }
  #-> hi5 hi4 hi3
```

I added a method to the refinement, but you can add, modify, rename or delete existing instance or class methods, add constant, and so on.

One last thing: refinements don't seem to work in IRB.
**:tidE]**

You could do it like so:

```
class Range
  def todown
    f,l = first,last
    l -= 1 if exclude_end?
    if block_given?
      while l >= f
        yield(l)
        l -= 1
      end
    else
      s = ''
      while l >= f
        s << l.to_s
        l -= 1
      end
      puts(s)
    end
  end
end

(2...7).todown
  #-> 65432
(3..5).todown { |i| print "hi#{i} " }
  #-> hi5 hi4 hi3
```

Though somewhat long, you'll see that most of Ruby's built-in methods (that are written in Ruby, rather than in C) are constructed in a similar fashion, to reduce as much as possible dependencies on methods in other classes.

Comment: If I simply copy and paste your code in an online interpreter (http://repl.it/languages/Ruby) I get `undefined method 'todown' for 2...7:Range
(repl):21:in 'initialize' `

Comment: It seems that online interpreter found at http://repl.it doesn't work properly. Everything works like a charm on a pc interpreter. Thanks!

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Ruby is meant to be expressive and human readable, so I don't think this method is a great one. `to_a` and `reverse_each` in the other answers are parts of Enumerable, and since they patch Range (an Enumerable), there is no dependency issue here. I don't think writing code like this is good advice, especially to beginners.

Comment: @LoganSerman, you're right. Ruby's core classes are often written like this, so they won't break if, in future, a change is made to a method in some other core class. But that's not the user's concern. If, for example, the user wrote this method using `to_a` and `reverse_each`, and one of those methods were changed in future, the user's code would not doubt break regardless of how this method was written. I'll do some editing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like:

```
(3..5).reverse_each { |i| print "hi#{i} " }
```

You could also patch Range with:

```
class Range
  def todown
    reverse_each do |i|
      if block_given?
        yield i
      else
        print i
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And that would allow you to do:

```
(3..5).todown { |i| print "hi#{i} " }
```

Comment: Still a bit unclear. Where do I put the `(3..5).todown { |i| puts "hi#{i} " }` part? Do I create a class object and then call the method `todown` ?

Comment: @Justin: you can use that anywhere that you can use a `Range` (ie anywhere). `(3..5)` creates a `Range`, so you can use that wherever you need it after you've made the patch.

Comment: @jbeck: I realised that when I tried to use a pc ruby interpreter instead of online one that I've found at http://repl.it. The online interpreter didn't want to run my code...

Comment: @Justin: yeah the online interpreters can be pretty spotty. But you can count on Range being in the MRI implementation of Ruby and #reverse_each is in Enumerable, so you'll always have that too.

Comment: Yes, `reverse_each`is defined on `Array`, but it's also defined on `Enumerable`. Does that suggest how you can simplify your method? I'm glad to see you've fixed your original answer.

Comment: Good catch @CarySwoveland. I knew that `#each` and `#reverse_each` were from `Enumerable`, but I didn't recall that `Range` included it. I also think it's a little strange that it does, since a `Range` doesn't have to act enumerable (eg if you create it with `Float`s).

Comment: That is quite unusual.  `Range.each` will raise an exception if the range's endpoints are floats (even if they are equal). I guess the Ruby monks figured that's not a good reason to deny `Range` all the benefits from including `Enumerable` when the range has a finite number of elements. I would agree.  Incidentally, I just noticed `(1.0..2.0).size
 #=> 2`.

Comment: `each` is not defined in `Enumerable`; it is defined on each class that includes `Enumerable`, including the class `Enumerator`. That `each` in turn invokes `each` defined on the original receiver's class.  All those `each`'s are what makes `include Enumerable` work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, by making use of `to_a` to make the range into an array and then using `reverse_each` to yield if the block is given.

Else, we will print it.

```
class Range
  def todown
    reverse_each do |v| 
       yield v if block_given? 
       print v unless block_given?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This won't actually work, `def Range.todown` will define a class method, not an instance method. @jbeck's solution is the same thing but uses an instance method.

Comment: @LoganSerman forgot that. I'm new to ruby. Didn't check that. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @LoganSerman, I missed that. My brain read `def Range` as `class Range`. @Amit, I think you just need to change `def` to `class` in your first line of code.

Comment: This is still a little off, since it will execute the `puts v` regardless of whether a block is given.

Comment: Amit, my comment on jbeck's answer applies to yours as well.